# How to ignore / exclude index file from VS Code / Intellisense / Autocomplete?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, circular-dependency

I am working on a library project which has a `lib.ts` file at the workspace root which defines all public exports of the library as follows:

```
export * from "./a/a.ts"
export * from "./b/b.ts"
export * from "./c/c.ts"
```

I am also using VS Code autocomplete (ctrl + space) a lot to let VS Code organize/add imports automatically while I am developing. Unfortunately, Intellisense keeps importing from `lib.ts` rather than from the original file that defined the export.

So, assuming that `a` needs `b`, VS Code would organize the imports in `a.ts` as follows:

```
import { b } from "../lib"

export const a = b(1)
```

That results in circular dependencies at build time, which seems to confuse `rollup`:

```
  lib.ts -> a/a.ts -> lib.ts -> b/b.ts
```

Is there a way to tell VS Code to ignore `lib.ts` and import `b` from its original source, like so?

```
import { b } from "../b/b"

export const a = b(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem and found this setting in the preferences:

`typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns`

In your case you could add a glob like this:

```
{
  "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": [
    "../../lib.ts"
  ],
}
```

and then it won't suggest imports from any `lib.ts` files that you don't want to import from.